# True only when going from High to Low

Tags: java, boolean-logic, boolean-operations, structured-text

I’m trying to think a generalized way to program something that is True( does some logic) only when a bit goes from high to low.

The programming language doesn’t matter but I prefer JAVA or Structured Text.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you talking about leading edge detection ? If yes, then you need to track the state. Usually this is done with a shift register. Bump value A to reg 2 and take new value B into reg 1 then compare.

Answer (score 1):

Within the IEC61131-3 world using ST this can be achieved using [F_TRIG](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_standard/9007199329131019.html&id=) (Falling trigger).

Simply declare an F_TRIG and call it with a boolean and check if F_TRIG is enabled (Q):

```
VAR
   yourFTrig : F_TRIG;
END_VAR
------------------------
yourFTrig(CLK := yourBoolean);
IF yourFTrig.Q THEN
   // Your code that shall be executed only when we have a falling trigger
END_IF
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect rising or falling edge, program have to work in cycles. In PLC IEC 61131-3, it already works in cycles. There are 2 ways to detect edge. One is already described by @Jacob. It is to use `F_TRIG` and `R_TRIG` function blocks.

Let me demonstrate underlying principle of this logic.

```
PROGRAM demo
  VAR
    xStart : BOOL; (* Bit that we detect edge on *) 
    xStartM: BOOL; (* Bit to store value from last cycle *)
  END_VAR
  
  IF xStart AND NOT xStartM THEN
      (* Rising edge detected *)
  END_IF

  IF NOT xStart AND xStartM THEN
      (* Falling edge detected *)
  END_IF
  xStart := xStartM;
END_PROGRAM;
```

Pay attention to `xStart := xStartM;`. Everything that is above this line will have `xStartM` equal to value of `xStart` from the last cycle. It means that if we use ёШАё before that line we may find that `xStart` is `TRUE` but `xStartM` still not, thus it is the moment we switch.

In JAVA in order to that you use the same technic, but you have to do it all in a while. I do not know JAVA, but here is how it could look in PHP.

```
<?php
$am = false;
while(true) {
    $a = getA();
    if ($a && !$am) {
        // rise edge
    }
    if (!$a && $am) {
        // fall edge
    }
    $am = $a;
    sleep(1);
}
```